# access file from static folder with template tags inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, django, templates, tags

I have an app which creates file location from submit button

```
json_path = os.path.join('json', request.POST['submit'], '.json' )
```

This gives the file location under `\static\json\` folder.

I am sending this using dictionary to template

```
render_dict = {
        'json_path':json_path,
    }
```

Inside javascript, I have the following

```
<script>

map.addSource('locationData', {
                    type: 'geojson',
                    data: "location of the json file needs to be provided here"
                    });

</script>
```

can anybody suggest if this can be done through template tagging?

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed this by following work around. But would appreciate if anything better is suggested.

1. In render_dict i send a list instead of string -

   render_dict = {
           'json_path':[json_path],
       }
2. Inside javascript I used the following -

   map.addSource('locationData', {
                   type: 'geojson',

   {% autoescape on %}
                   data: "{{json_path|safe|escape|cut:"'"|cut:"["|cut:"]"}}"
                   {% endautoescape %}

   ```
               });
   ```